# android NavigationView not found

Tags: android, gradle, jar, material-design

I have the following xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
       />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but im getting the error that `no such class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

here is my sdk configuration in gradle:

```
 minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

I'm not allowed to use jcenter or a remote repository in my project for security reasons so i have to always include dependencies as jar file.  How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error because you need the Design Support Library.

Download with the `SDK Manager` the `Android Support Repository`, than you can find the last version of the library here:

```
<android-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.aar
```

Copy it in your `libs` directory then add the dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'android.support.design:design:23.0.1@aar'
}
```

Comment: is there two design ? in your gradle dependencies you put down the word design twice, is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, the first string before the colon is the package name. You can also leave empty like this `compile ':design:23.0.1@aar'`. The important part is the the second part and the version number that identify the file.

Comment: I do not recommend copying the AAR directly. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37638689/1172494

Comment: Generally neither do I recommend to copy the AAR directly but the OP asked for a method to include the library file: _"I'm not allowed to use jcenter or a remote repository in my project for security reasons so i have to always include dependencies as jar file."_

Answer (score 1):

Go to grade. Build file click on the build icon, select add dependency /library then click on design library then sync.
Make sure to add appCompat library to ensure backwards compatibility for your app.

Comment: The support repository has new updates to be safe make sure you have the latest

Answer (score 0):

In `SDK Manager`, make sure you have downloaded `Android Support Repository`.

Then, add this to your `build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the dependency

In the layout file use:

```
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
```

for the `navigationView` on `androidx`